# Connected to a wifi network, but unable to access internet - freshly installed 14.01

Tags: wireless, drivers, internet, dell, broadcom

I have a DELL Inspiron N5010 laptop and I have dual boot with Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04. I had Ubuntu 13.10 and now I installed 14.04 using live media (I did not upgrade.) Now I am not able to access Internet via Wi-Fi. It is connecting to wifi without any problem, but just Internet doesn't work. In Windows 8.1 it works fine.

I am able to access internet via USB serial modem, but not via WiFi.

Here is few information that I am able to collect from laptop.

```
    user@laptop:~$ cat /etc/lsb-release; uname -a
    DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
    DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
    DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
    DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04 LTS"
    Linux machine 3.13.0-24-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 10 19:11:08 UTC 2014 x86_64         x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
    user@laptop:~$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net
    12:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless         Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Dell Inspiron M5010 / XPS 8300 [1028:0010]
        Kernel driver in use: wl
    13:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.         RTL8101E/RTL8102E         PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 02)
        Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0447]
        Kernel driver in use: r8169
    user@laptop:~$ iwconfig
    eth0      no wireless extensions.


    lo        no wireless extensions.


    wlan0     IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:off/any  
              Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   
              Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
              Power Management:off

    user@laptop:~$ iwconfig
    ppp0      no wireless extensions.


    eth0      no wireless extensions.


    lo        no wireless extensions.


    wlan0     IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:off/any  
              Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   
              Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
              Power Management:off

    user@laptop:~$ rfkill list all
    0: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
    1: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
    2: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
    user@laptop:~$ lsmod
    Module                  Size  Used by
    ppp_deflate            12950  0 
    bsd_comp               12921  0 
    ppp_async              17413  1 
    crc_ccitt              12707  1 ppp_async
    option                 42468  3 
    usb_wwan               20429  1 option
    usbserial              45014  9 option,usb_wwan
    usb_storage            62209  0 
    bnep                   19624  2 
    rfcomm                 69160  8 
    joydev                 17381  0 
    snd_hda_codec_hdmi     46207  1 
    snd_hda_codec_idt      54645  1 
    btusb                  32412  0 
    bluetooth             395423  22 bnep,btusb,rfcomm
    hid_generic            12548  0 
    usbhid                 52616  0 
    hid                   106148  2 hid_generic,usbhid
    uvcvideo               80885  0 
    videobuf2_vmalloc      13216  1 uvcvideo
    videobuf2_memops       13362  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
    videobuf2_core         40664  1 uvcvideo
    videodev              134688  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core
    dell_wmi               12761  0 
    sparse_keymap          13948  1 dell_wmi
    snd_hda_intel          52355  3 
    snd_hda_codec         192906  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_hda_intel
    snd_hwdep              13602  1 snd_hda_codec
    snd_pcm               102099  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
    snd_page_alloc         18710  2 snd_pcm,snd_hda_intel
    snd_seq_midi           13324  0 
    snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
    dell_laptop            18168  0 
    dcdbas                 14928  1 dell_laptop
    snd_rawmidi            30144  1 snd_seq_midi
    lib80211_crypt_tkip    17619  0 
    intel_powerclamp       14705  0 
    coretemp               13435  0 
    kvm_intel             143060  0 
    kvm                   451511  1 kvm_intel
    snd_seq                61560  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
    psmouse               102222  0 
    wl                   4207846  0 
    intel_ips              18664  0 
    serio_raw              13462  0 
    i915                  783485  8 
    snd_seq_device         14497  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
    lib80211               14381  2 wl,lib80211_crypt_tkip
    cfg80211              484040  1 wl
    lpc_ich                21080  0 
    snd_timer              29482  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
    mei_me                 18627  0 
    snd                    69238  17         snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_raw        midi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device,snd_seq_midi
    mei                    82274  1 mei_me
    drm_kms_helper         52758  1 i915
    soundcore              12680  1 snd
    drm                   302817  4 i915,drm_kms_helper
    i2c_algo_bit           13413  1 i915
    wmi                    19177  1 dell_wmi
    video                  19476  1 i915
    mac_hid                13205  0 
    parport_pc             32701  0 
    ppdev                  17671  0 
    lp                     17759  0 
    parport                42348  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
    ahci                   25819  4 
    r8169                  67581  0 
    libahci                32168  1 ahci
    mii                    13934  1 r8169
    user@laptop:
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you add the output of `nm-tool` to your question?

Comment: Please do what is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do>

Answer (score 0):

1. Do you have an IP address?

   - `ifconfig`
2. Can you ping your router/gateway

   - `ping 192.168.1.1` (possibly different)
3. Can you ping Google's DNS servers?

   - `ping 8.8.8.8`

If the above steps are successful, then you're most likely experiencing DNS issues.  If any of the above steps fail, you should focus on that part of the network.